# Live "retranslation" from microphone to speaker (megaphone-like)

Tags: android, audio, live, audio-streaming, speech

as I could not find a suitable app in the Play store, I want to try coding it myself.

I need a plain vanilla megaphone under Android (4.1 and later):

as I speek into the headset, I want the audio "stream" to be spoken through the loudspeaker - in realtime, without any intermittent recording, streaming etc.

**Is this "megaphone functionality" directly supported through APIs?**

Is there *any* example app (with or without sourcecode) with retranslation functionality that I might have missed?

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: Even if this works, I think you'll get an awful feedback noise immediately.

Comment: Are you trying to control the hardware mixer to make the microphone audible out of the speaker with zero latency?  Or are you trying to play back the microphone input to the speaker with software?

Comment: @Ridcully: I understand the issue, but since it works with conventional megaphones I cannot see why it shouldn't be able using a smartphone. 

Otherwise: I'm not sure how it can be done - open to all possibilities.

Comment: In a conventional megaphone, the output is well focused *away* from the microphone to limit the feedback.

Comment: You'll probably be looking at a combined (recording+playback) latency of at least 100 ms. Probably a lot more, depending on the device (and `AudioTrack` doesn't use the low-latency path introduced in JellyBean anyway). So even ignoring the feedback concerns, there's a risk that the latency will be so high that the user experience will become awkward (because of the lag between when you say something and when it's heard from the loudspeaker).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the API functions, but not without buffering/streaming to the speaker. You basically have to route what you get from `AudioRecord` into an `AudioTrack`. You can probably find code examples of this online.

As for the "ready-to-use" part, asking for 3rd-party recommendations is off-topic here. You may want to remove/rephrase that. Otherwise, your question is a target for closure.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I hope the rewording make my aim more clear.